# How to add a dictionary to a data frame while matching key values to columns names?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have the following data frame:

```
s1 = pd.Series({'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3})
s2 = pd.Series({'A': 4, 'B': 5, 'C': 6})
s3 = pd.Series({'A': 7, 'B': 8, 'C': 9})

df = pd.DataFrame([s1, s2, s3])
print(df)
```

I want to add the following s4, s5 and s6 series to the s1, s2 and s3 rows respectively, while creating a column with the dictionary keys if one doesn't exists already, and filling all the other column values with 0.

```
s4 = pd.Series({'D': 2, 'G': 8})
s5 = pd.Series({'E': 5})
s6 = pd.Series({'D': 6, 'E': 3})
```

The resulting data frame I want would look like this:

```
s7 = pd.Series({'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 2, 'G': 8, 'E': 0})
s8 = pd.Series({'A': 4, 'B': 5, 'C': 6, 'D': 0, 'G': 0, 'E': 5})
s9 = pd.Series({'A': 7, 'B': 8, 'C': 9, 'D': 6, 'G': 0, 'E': 3})

df2 = pd.DataFrame([s7, s8, s9])
print(df2)
```

Is there a way to easily do that?

Comment: ``pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([s4,s5,s6])], axis=1).fillna(0)``

Comment: df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([s4,s5,s6]).fillna(0))?

Comment: `df1 = pd.DataFrame([s4, s5, s6])`, `df.join(df1).fillna(0)`.